# Pythonic way of getting all consecutive 2-tuples from list

Tags: python

I have a sentence as a list of words, and I'm trying to extract all the bigrams (i.e. all the consecutive 2-tuples of words)  from it. So, if my sentence was

`['To', 'sleep', 'perchance', 'to', 'dream']`

I want to get back out

`[('To', 'sleep'), ('sleep', 'perchance'), ('perchance', 'to'), ('to', 'dream')]`

Currently, I'm using

`zip([sentence[i] for i in range(len(sentence) - 1)], [sentence[i+1] for i in range(len(sentence) - 1)]` and then iterating over this, but I can't help thinking there are more Pythonic ways of doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right track with `zip`. I suggest using list slicing instead of comprehensions.

```
seq = ['To', 'sleep', 'perchance', 'to', 'dream']
print zip(seq, seq[1:])
```

Result:

```
[('To', 'sleep'), ('sleep', 'perchance'), ('perchance', 'to'), ('to', 'dream')]
```

Note that the arguments to `zip` don't have to be the same length, so it's fine that `seq` is longer than `seq[1:]`.

Comment: What if seq is a set()? Should I use zip(list(seq), list(seq)[1:]) or is there a better way?

Comment: @ppw0 First, a word of caution: [sets are unordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). From a semantic standpoint you should not try to get "consecutive items" out of a set, because it may not have a consistent opinion on which of its items are consecutive. But if you still want to try, I suggest using wim's solution, since it doesn't depend on slicing like mine does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one I prepared earlier.  It's from the [itertools recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the official python docs.

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    """Iterate in pairs

    >>> list(pairwise([0, 1, 2, 3]))
    [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
    >>> tuple(pairwise([])) == tuple(pairwise('x')) == ()
    True
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea but using slicing instead of indexing with `range`

```
>>> l =['To', 'sleep', 'perchance', 'to', 'dream']
>>> list(zip(l, l[1:]))
[('To', 'sleep'), ('sleep', 'perchance'), ('perchance', 'to'), ('to', 'dream')]
```

Comment: There's no need for the `[:-1]` (it creates an unnecessary list slice) as `zip` truncates the shorter argument.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! Learned something new, thanks.