# "Pythonic" way to return elements from an iterable as long as a condition based on previous element is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

I am working on some code that needs to constantly take elements from an iterable as long as a condition based on (or related to) the previous element is true. For example, let's say I have a list of numbers:

```
lst = [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1, 2.2, 4.1, 4.9, 5.2, 4.3, 3.2]
```

And let's use a simple condition: the number does not differ from the previous number more than 1. So the expected output would be

```
[0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1]
```

Normally, `itertools.takewhile` would be a good choice, but in this case it's a bit annoying because the first element doesn't have a previous element to query. The following code returns an empty list because for the first element the code queries the last element.

```
from itertools import takewhile
res1 = list(takewhile(lambda x: abs(lst[lst.index(x)-1] - x) <= 1., lst))
print(res1)
# []
```

I managed to write some "ugly" code to work around:

```
res2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    res2.append(x)
    # Make sure index is not out of range
    if i < len(lst) - 1:
        if not abs(lst[i+1] - x) <= 1.:
            break
print(res2)
# [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1]
```

However, I feel like there should be more "pythonic" way to code this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related:  [Pythonic way of getting all consecutive 2-tuples from list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27362611/674039).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can write your own version of `takewhile` where the predicate takes both the current and previous values:

```py
def my_takewhile(iterable, predicate):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    try:
        previous = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        # next(iterable) raises if the iterable is empty
        return
    yield previous
    for current in iterable:
        if not predicate(previous, current):
            break
        yield current
        previous = current
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(my_takewhile(lst, lambda x, y: abs(x - y) <= 1))
[0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution using *assignment expression* `:=` for Python >= 3.8:

```
lst = [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1, 2.2, 4.1, 4.9, 5.2, 4.3, 3.2]

pred = lambda cur, prev: abs(cur-prev) <= 1
p = None
res = [p := i for i in lst if p is None or pred(p, i)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a sequence of tuples by zipping the list with a sequence that prepends the first element of the list to the list; the resulting sequence
of tuples pairs the first element with itself (so that `abs(x-x)` is guaranteed less than 1) and each other element with its preceding element.

```
a = lst                        == x1       x2       x3       x4       ...
b = chain(islice(lst, 1), lst) == x1       x1       x2       x3       ...
zip(a, b)                      == (x1, x1) (x2, x1) (x3, x2) (x4, x3) ...
```

Then

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, chain
>>> lst = [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1, 2.2, 4.1, 4.9, 5.2, 4.3, 3.2]
>>> def close(t): return abs(t[0] - t[1]) <= 1
...
>>> [x for x, _ in takewhile(close, zip(lst, chain(islice(lst, 1), lst)))]
[0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1]
```

If you prefer, you can define `prepend` as shown in the `itertools` documentation, and write

```
[x for x, _ in takewhile(close, zip(lst, prepend(lst[0], lst)))]
```

You can also just use ordinary list slicing in this case instead of `islice` (which is essentially just inlining the aforementioned `prepend` function, as `lst[:1] == [lst[0]]`).

```
[x for x, _ in takewhile(close, zip(lst, chain(lst[:1], lst)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

A little later but, here there is another solution, perhaps is not the most *Pythonic* way:

Maybe you could consider a recursive approach. The function `reduce_list` receive as parameter a list (your `lst` variable) and the current item of this list (the first one). There is a variable named `list_result` that will store the items that accomplish the condition. If the list has only one item, then we don't have against what compare it, for that reason we will return `list_result`. Otherwise We get the next item in the list (the second one) and if the condition is `True`, then We store that item. If the condition is `False`, then We save the last one `current` and stop the recursion.

```
list_result = []
def reduce_list(lst, current):
  if len(lst) == 1:
    return list_result
  
  the_next = lst[1]
  if (abs(current - the_next) <= 1):
    list_result.append(current)
  else:
    list_result.append(current)
    return
  
  lst = lst[1:] # Set the lst as the rest of the list itself.
  current = lst[0] # current will be the first one of the rest.
  reduce_list(lst, current)

reduce_list(lst, lst[0])
print(list_result)
```

Output: `[0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.1]`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a simple for loop. Having an integer you can manipulate will allow you to easily compare multiple values within the same list.

```py
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
  if(abs(lst[i] - lst[i-1]) < 1):
    # do stuff
```

The index starts at 1 and not zero so that you can compare the initial two values.

Alternatively, if you need to do something special with the first element, then start the for loop at 0 and add a simple if statement for the first case:

```py
  if(i == 0):
    # do stuff
  elif( normal condition ):
```